# can't get rid of WARNING: your installation of Flutter is 90 days old. when building in AndroidStudio

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app using flutter as a learning exercise. When i run the app from within AndroidStudio, i always get this warning

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦ WARNING: your installation of Flutter is 90 days old.                      ¦
¦                                                                            ¦    
¦ To update to the latest version, run "flutter upgrade".                    ¦
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running flutter upgrade doesn't get rid of this warning. 
flutter upgrade says that the latest beta is 0.7.1, but my project always builds with 0.5.1
Running from command line does not have this warning. Only when running from in AndroidStudio.

```
$ flutter channel
Flutter channels:
* beta
  dev
  master
$ flutter --version
Flutter 0.5.1 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c7ea3ca377 (3 months ago) • 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
Engine • revision 1ed25ca7b7
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

$ flutter -v doctor
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 0.5.1 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision c7ea3ca377 (3 months ago), 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
• Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
…
```

But upgrade does this:

```
$ flutter upgrade
Upgrading Flutter from C:\src\flutter...
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
   09fe34708..3c624f8b2  dev        -> origin/dev
   7f0f938de..7a07b28c9  master     -> origin/master    
 * [new tag]             v0.7.1     -> v0.7.1
```

I've tried to fix this more ways that I can even list. I'm flummoxed. What's going on?

Comment: Yooiu might need to create a bug report at the flutter GIT
https://github.com/flutter/flutter

Comment: Do you get the same error if you install 0.7.0?

Comment: Go to your flutter sdk folder. Do a `git pull`. Then `flutter doctor`. Should solves things

Comment: You should check that the version of flutter android studio is using is the same on that you have on the path.

Comment: There is a new beta expected any day now that should solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 29th Aug 2018:

Flutter has just now released 0.6.0 (Flutter beta 6). You are getting that warning because Flutter did not release any stable update for 90 days.

**Note**: May need to restart system after upgrading.